# How to update 1:1 relations in Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have 2 models as below

```
class Communication extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;
}

class Filter extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup>
     */
    protected $usergroup;
}
```

Template as below

```
<f:form class="form-horizontal" name="communication" action="update" object="{communication}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 control-label" for="bodytext">{f:translate(key: 'text.usergroup')}</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10">
            <f:for each="{usergroups}" as="group">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <f:form.checkbox property="filter.usergroup" value="{group.uid}" /> {group.title}
                </label>
            </f:for>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{f:translate(key: 'button.update')}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:form>
```

When I try to update a Communication with `$this->communicationRepository->update($communication)`, it always creates a new Filter rather than updating its own. Why this?

Comment: Can you add the actual form rendered in your browser, i.e. after rendering it with fluid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no relation to the filter that is already there. For keeping the filter you need to say what id it has. I found out it works with an __identity field:

EDIT: it is probably better to wrap the field with an if condition in case there is no filter set

```
<f:if condition="{communication.filter.uid}">
    <f:form.hidden name="communication[filter][__identity]" value="{communication.filter.uid}" />
</f:if>
```

Not sure, but it is possible that is also works with an uid property field:

```
<f:form.hidden property="filter.uid" />
```

Comment: I would say that still should work w/o adding anything manually, as he is already using a `property` attribute accessing the filter, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Andreas Wolf - without adding the __identity field the filter can not be mapped, a new filter is added and the relation to the old one is lost.

Comment: @Dmitri I know that, but I suspect that Extbase/Fluid should add that automatically once you access the property in a form element.

Comment: @Andreas Wolf - this is not the case

Comment: @DimitriL. Thanks for your hint, the <f:form.hidden> did work, but it also allows people to change its value easily somehow, which might mess up other filters.

Comment: Finally, I use $communication->getFilter()->_setProperty('uid', $communication->_getCleanProperty('filter')->getUid()); to do the trick.